# How to make a synchronized LiDAR/Camera rig for Autonomous Driving research?

Tags: cameras, lidar, autonomous-car

I am just starting a research project at my university involving sensor fusion between a Camera and a LiDAR device to detect and localize cars around our vehicle (bounded boxes around cars in 3D point-cloud). We need a rig having one Camera and one LiDAR to capture data, which we will label manually, and later we will train a deep neural model that takes the advantage of color intensity and depth information for increased accuracy. However, upon basic online search, I found that we'll need a frame synchronized rig for such purpose. I also found that usually LiDAR devices have a sync port for such purpose, but I don't know how I can connect it with a camera so that both devices generate frames capturing the exact same instant in time? Do usual cameras have such a port or do I need to buy a special camera?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> However, upon basic online search, I found that we'll need a frame synchronized rig for such purpose

This is not a simple problem and there exist several solutions, based on project needs, to achieve what you are trying to do. A basic search isn't enough. This forum is for specific questions / errors you want resolved.

As a starting point, you can take a look at [Autoware's object detection](https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/detection/vision_darknet_detect.html). They have a pre-trained network you can use as a starting point. If you do not use a triggered camera, you may co-calibrate your lidar and camera (again [autoware has one](https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/sensing/autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator.html)) to get transforms between them and use that as an input to your network.

You could also take a look at [lidar-bonnetal](https://github.com/PRBonn/lidar-bonnetal) who use range images projected from a lidar. Maybe you can incorporate color information in them?

You will also find several newer works on ArXiV like [RoIFusion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.04554.pdf), [end-to-end approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.04602.pdf), etc.

Answer (score 1):

As your application does not need on-the-fly sync between the devices, running an SW-based time lag estimation is also one way to do it.

The following materials might help to start with.

https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr

Spatiotemporal camera-LiDAR calibration: A targetless and structureless approach, C Park, P Moghadam, S Kim, S Sridharan, C Fookes

But please be aware that this is one of the most difficult problems when you use a multi-modal sensor.